# JSON file with lots of arrays: parsing in Android.

Tags: android, json, parsing, sdk

I have a JSON file with lots of attributes. I've parsed JSON files before using the methods provided by the Android SDK. But I have absolutely no clue on how to handle this file because the attributes are in arrays.

Anyone has a guess?

```
{
"properties": {
    "position" : { "valueType": "text" },
    "image" : { "valueType": "text" },
    "architekt" : { "valueType": "text" },
    "baustil" : { "valueType": "text" },
    "besuchbar" : { "valueType": "text" },
    "bildbeschreibung" : { "valueType": "text" },
    "bundesland" : { "valueType": "text" },
    "eintrittspreis" : { "valueType": "text" },
    "geo_lat" : { "valueType": "text" },
    "geo_lon" : { "valueType": "text" },
    "hoehe" : { "valueType": "text" },
    "internetpraesenz" : { "valueType": "text" },
    "land" : { "valueType": "text" },
    "oeffnungszeiten" : { "valueType": "text" },
    "ort" : { "valueType": "text" },
    "parkplaetze" : { "valueType": "text" },
    "plz" : { "valueType": "text" },
    "sehenswuerdigkeit" : { "valueType": "text" },
    "strasse" : { "valueType": "text" }
},
"items": [
    {
        "label": "Assf",
        "position": ["Testroute::2","Rathausroute::2"],
        "image": [" http:\/\/134.108.119.74\/mediawiki-1.18.2\/index.php\/Datei:Rathaus_Goeppingen.png"],
        "bildbeschreibung": ["Vorderansicht des Rathaus G\u00f6ppingen"],
        "sehenswuerdigkeit": ["Rathaus G\u00f6ppingen"]
    },
    {
        "label": "Burg Hohenstaufen",
        "position": ["Testroute::2","Rathausroute::13"],
        "image": [" http:\/\/134.108.119.74\/mediawiki-1.18.2\/index.php\/Datei:Burg Hohenstaufen Fresko.jpg"],
        "architekt": ["Friedrich I. von Schwaben"],
        "baustil": ["H\u00f6henburg, Gipfellage"],
        "besuchbar": ["wahr"],
        "bildbeschreibung": ["\u00c4lteste Abbildung der Burg Hohenstaufen aus dem Jahre 1470"],
        "bundesland": ["Baden-W\u00fcrttemberg"],
        "eintrittspreis": ["unentgeltlich besuchbar"],
        "geo_lat": ["48.743056"],
        "geo_lon": ["9.716389"],
        "hoehe": ["19 Meter"],
        "internetpraesenz": ["http:\/\/www.awdfasdfa.de"],
        "land": ["Germany"],
        "oeffnungszeiten": ["Immer Ge\u00f6ffnet"],
        "ort": ["G\u00f6ppingen Hohenstaufen"],
        "parkplaetze": ["falsch"],
        "plz": ["73037"],
        "sehenswuerdigkeit": ["Burg Hohenstaufen"]
    },
    {
        "label": "Test",
        "position": ["Testroute::1","Rathausroute::23"],
        "image": [" http:\/\/134.108.119.74\/mediawiki-1.18.2\/index.php\/Datei:Rathaus_Goeppingen.png"],
        "architekt": ["Joseph Poelaert"],
        "baustil": ["Barock"],
        "besuchbar": ["wahr"],
        "bildbeschreibung": ["Vorderansicht des Rathaus G\u00f6ppingens"],
        "bundesland": ["Baden-W\u00fcrttemberg"],
        "eintrittspreis": ["f\u00fcr Umme"],
        "geo_lat": ["48.7025"],
        "geo_lon": ["9.65277"],
        "hoehe": ["19 Meter"],
        "internetpraesenz": ["http:\/\/www.awdfasdfa.de"],
        "land": ["Germany"],
        "oeffnungszeiten": ["Mo: 9:30 bis 13:30 und 14:00 bis 18:30 &lt;br \/&gt; Sa&amp;So: 10:00 bis 20:00"],
        "ort": ["G\u00f6ppingen"],
        "parkplaetze": ["wahr"],
        "plz": ["70825"],
        "sehenswuerdigkeit": ["Rathaus G\u00f6ppingen"],
        "strasse": ["Robert-Bosch-str. 12"]
    }
]
```

}

Comment: use Jackson http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Its pretty easy](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)

```
json = new JSONObject(textThatISJSON);
JSONArray properties = json.getJSONArray("properties");
JSONArray position = properties.getJSONArray("position");
```